# WorkbookOpen event does not work with AutoFilterDateGrouping

Tags: vba, excel

I have created the following vba script in personal.xlsb, in ThisWorkbook (Excel 2010):

```
Sub Workbook_Open()

     Application.ActiveWindow.AutoFilterDateGrouping = False

End Sub
```

It does not work. 
I get vba runtime error: 91 object variable or with block variable not set.
Although it works if run manually after file is opened.

The intention is to have the AutoFilterDateGrouping set to False automatically for all newly opened files.

Comment: Try to add 'Stop' before 'Application.ActiveWindow...' and re-open the workbook. Then in debug mode watch what is not set (maybe no ActiveWindow yet?).

Comment: Your code runs when the Personal macro workbook is opened, at which point there is no workbook active.

Comment: I understand this, but how could I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I found dirty solution:

Module:

> Sub Startup()
>
> ActiveWindow.AutoFilterDateGrouping = False
>
> End Sub

Workbook section:

> Sub Workbook_Open()
>
> Application.OnTime Now() + TimeSerial(0, 0, 1), "Startup"
>
> End Sub